# SQL Formula...Adding Rows Only for Matching ID

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Can someone please help with the SQL with this formula.

If category_id of product_id(eg.12) = a given number(eg.99) then
Add another product_id(12) with another given category number (eg.123)

The result should end up with multiple rows with the same product_id but different category_id's
product_id (12) = 99
product_id (12) = 123
product_id (12)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you just want `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t(product_id, category_id)
    select product_id, 123
    from t
    where category_id = 99;
```